# how to enable statistics using awk in linux

Tags: linux, virtual-machine

when I type the command stats.awk size.cvs, it says command not found on my virtual machine linux. Can someone help me get through sice Im new to linux and linux coding

Comment: What is `stats.awk`? It looks like an `awk` script that you think you have on your system but you don't. Or at least not in one of the PATH directories. Are you sure you have a copy of that script on your system?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are not trying to run any standard Linux tool, but a script written by someone else called "stats.awk"... and the file you want to operate on is called "size.cvs" (it is more likely called size.csv -- as this is likely a "Comma Separated Value" file).  Most Linux implementations do not allow you to just run a script unless the script is in your PATH and has the right permissions.

You could try "fully qualifying" the path of your **awk** script, but probably easiest is to just feed it into **awk**.  Try:

```
awk -f stats.awk size.cvs
```

To find out more information about your shell run:

```
man $SHELL
```

Or just Google for a tutorial on your shell (which is likely **bash**).  To find more about **awk**, again, try Googling for a tutorial on **awk**.

Comment: all good stuff, I would say `awk -f /full/path/to/script/stats.awk size.cvs` . Good luck to all.